# Count distinct entity only if all records with a particular id is same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let us consider the following table

```
col1   col2   col3
a      true   1
a      true   2
b      true   1
b      false  2
```

In the above table I need to count distinct col1 where col2 should be true.
But the condition is all the values for col1 (ie 'a') should be true.
It cannot fetch 'b' because it have one false.

Here is the sample query of what I have tried

```
select count(distinct(col1)) from table where col2 = 'true' and col2 != 'false'
```

But it shows result as two but what i need is 1.

I am using sql server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: @axiac sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one trick

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT col1
        FROM   table
        GROUP  BY col1
        HAVING Min(col2) = 'true'
               AND Max(col2) = 'true')a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT Col1)
    FROM YourTable YT
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM YourTable Y2
                    WHERE Col1 = YT.Col1
                        AND Col2 <> YT.Col2
        ) AND Col2 = 'True'
```

Answer (score 1):

Take all those `COL1` with either only true or only false and pick from this list those with true(outer query).

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.COL1)
FROM
    (SELECT COL1 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    GROUP BY COL1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COL2) = 1) A
INNER JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.COL1 = B.COL1 AND B.COL2 = 'true';
```